# How to remove filters applied on excel by SAS code?

Tags: excel, sas

My sas code reads a excel file to feed the data but sometimes user may save the file with filter applied on that, in that case SAS do not feed in the full data but data after filter applied. 
Is there a way to remove the filters using SAS. Something using DDE or ODS may be?

Thanks!!

Comment: It should be possible to do that with a COM object from SAS. I think it's possible to create an object (like CreateObject from VBA or VBScript) from SAS, then you have access to most functionnality of Excel objects. Alternatively, it's possible to drive the process from Excel, and call SAS from COM, with `CreateObject("SAS.Application")`.

Comment: Have also a look at this: [Re: DDE to read Excel file with autofilter turned on?](http://compgroups.net/comp.soft-sys.sas/re-dde-to-read-excel-file-with-autofilter-t/1615849)

Comment: Have you tried putting a macro into Excel to remove filtering upon save?

Comment: How are you reading in the file? Please post example code.

Answer (score 0):

I am using PROC IMPORT to import excel file. Even if there are filters my program is reading all the data.. Check your code once again..